# Aren't static variables in an Objective-C class method shared across all subclasses?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, static-variables, class-method

I'm really perplexed. I have a class A with a class method that returns a shared cache instance:

```
+ (NSCache *)itemCache {
    static NSCache *itemCache;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        itemCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    });
    return itemCache;
}
```

I also have a subclass B of class A.

Whenever I call `[A itemCache]` I get one instance of the cache. Whenever I call `[B itemCache]` I get a different instance of the cache.

Are static variables unique to the particular class the method is called on? I thought they were shared across all subclasses.

**Edit** Nevermind, there was something else going. The world does indeed work like I thought it did. I have an app target and a test target. Class A was being included in both targets. Class B was only in the app target.

Comment: how do you know you get 2 different instances?

Comment: Because I logged them and they have different memory addresses.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", [A itemCache], [B itemCache], [C itemCache]);` (I actually have two subclasses of A) logs "<NSCache: 0xe87a0a0> <NSCache: 0x14da7d00> <NSCache: 0x14da7d00>"

Comment: Please show us all your code, as I cannot reproduce it. `<NSCache: 0x1002000e0> <NSCache: 0x1002000e0> <NSCache: 0x1002000e0>`

Comment: OK, figured it out. I have an app target and a test target. Class A was being included in both targets. Classes B and C were only in the app target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces the expected behavior:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
+ (NSCache *)itemCache;
@end

@implementation A
+ (NSCache *)itemCache {
    static NSCache *itemCache;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        itemCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    });
    return itemCache;
}

@end

@interface B : A
@end
@implementation B
@end


@interface C : A
@end
@implementation C
@end



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", [A itemCache], [B itemCache], [C itemCache]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

logs:

```
<NSCache: 0x1002000e0> <NSCache: 0x1002000e0> <NSCache: 0x1002000e0>
```

your issue must be else-where.